# Windows forms and SQL cmd syntax error

Tags: sql, windows, forms

Just want to use windows forms interface to insert data into the database.
I think the code is right, but it is giving me an error saying "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'."

[image with tables names here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yt1pr.png)

```
try
{
            string cmdString = @"insert into User (userName, userEmail, userBalance, userTickets) VALUES (@userName, @userEmail, @userBalance, @userTickets)" +
                                "insert into Account (accountName, accountPassword) VALUES (@accountName, @accountPassword)";

            // Connection 
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("i dont know if is safe to show the con string...but i know its right");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdString, con);
            con.Open();

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@userName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtUserName.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userEmail", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtemail.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userBalance", SqlDbType.Money).Value = 100;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userTickets", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 3;
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountID", null); 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtUserName.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountPassword", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtPassword.Text;

            // Execute command
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            //MessageBox.Show("Data saved!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

Can somebody give me a hand?

Answer (score 1):

`User` is a reserved word.

You need to enclose it in square brackets:

```
string cmdString = @"insert into [User] (userName, userEmail, userBalance, userTickets) VALUES (@userName, @userEmail, @userBalance, @userTickets)" +
                    "insert into Account (accountName, accountPassword) VALUES (@accountName, @accountPassword)";
```

Doing this will tell SQL to treat it as a table name and not the reserved word.

Comment: Wooow...really? So frustrating and yet so simple to resolve. thank you.

Comment: @Manuel Costa You should also be careful to terminate your commands with a semicolon `;`. And you may even want a line break between them.